# Receive data on server side with django-websocket-redis?

Tags: python, ios, django, sockets, websocket

I'm working with django-websocket-redis lib, that allow establish websockets over uwsgi in separated django loop. 
By the documentation I understand well how to send data from server through websockets, but I don't understand how to receive.

Basically I have client and I want to send periodically from the client to server status. I don't understand what I need to do, to handle receiving messages from client on server side? What URL I should use on client?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using periodically ajax calls from client to server. From documentation:

> A client wishing to trigger events on the server side, shall use
>   XMLHttpRequests (Ajax), as they are much more suitable, rather than
>   messages sent via Websockets. The main purpose for Websockets is to
>   communicate asynchronously from the server to the client.

Unfortunately I was unable to find the way to achieve it using just websocket messages.